# Arranging JTable columns from right to left

Tags: java, swing, jtable

When I add columns to `JTable`, By default, they're arranged from left to right.
e.g. if I add in this order (Left to right):

```
col1,col2,col3
```

I will get:

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
```

But I want this:

```
+------+------+------+
| col3 | Col2 | Col1 |
+------+------+------+
```

How can I make a `JTable` that arrange columns from right to left?

Comment: Either put them in the table that way, or show then in a locale that would normally have text run right-to-left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT) or applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT) will do the trick. 
Please refer to java doc for further clarifications

[setComponentOrientation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setComponentOrientation%28java.awt.ComponentOrientation%29)

[applyComponentOrientation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#applyComponentOrientation%28java.awt.ComponentOrientation%29)

> Alternatively you can just reverse the arrays for column names array and
>   row data arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I did it by setting `.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)` on the JTable.

Thanks